# How to install Microsoft Office 2013 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

My system is running on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) and I have already installed wine-1.6.2, and when I go and double click on setup.exe icon, I get the following Setup Error dialog:

> Setup can't  find or validate an installation file. Please try
>   reinstall Office from your installation source, or if you install from
>   a downloaded package,please re-install. if you continue to have
>   problems,please contact Microsoft or your system adminstrator.

Is there any way to install Office 2013 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not install MS Office on `wine`.

Ubuntu has *LibreOffice*, it's almost the same, and it supports MS Office document formats.

Comment: Well I am shifting to back to Microsoft powerpoint 2013 because LibreOffice is changing the format of the content in the .pptx slides.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Microsoft office online 
download link and more information [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/run-microsoft-office-web-apps-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a great alternative, but I am looking at installing Office 2013 on my PC.